# How to sort on descending order form a column which has both int and float values in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have a column called `chapterNumber` with the datatype `varchar` which stores both `int` and `float` values.

for only Int value if I do `order by chapterNumber desc` it works fine but when there are both float and int values in there `order by chapterNumber desc` doesn't work and results in

```
Chapter 6.5

Chapter 6

Chapter 52.5

Chapter 52

Chapter 5.2

Chapter 5

Chapter 4.5

Chapter 4
```

I want the numbers to appear in an descending order

Comment: Convert to the same data type and then you can compare, in this case, a Float can not be an integer, but an Integer can be a Float, so give that shot.  Hint - use of CAST might be helpful.  Then just add Order By (colname) DESC after the WHERE statement.

Comment: Note that ordering numbers as strings won't work when you have 2-digit numbers. `12` will go before `2`.

Comment: Indeed, you want the value of the number not the written word for the indexing.

Answer (score 1):

Extract the number at the end of the chapter string, and convert it to a numeric datatype so they can be compared.

```
ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(chapterNumber, '', -1) AS DECIMAL) DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

To sort a column in descending order that contains both integer and float values stored as varchar in MySQL, you can convert the varchar values to numbers before sorting.
You can use the CAST() or CONVERT() function to achieve this.
Here's an example query to sort the chapterNumber column in descending order:

`SELECT * FROM your_table ORDER BY CAST(chapterNumber AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) DESC; In this query: CAST(chapterNumber AS DECIMAL(10, 2))`

converts the varchar values in the chapterNumber column to a decimal (floating-point) number with a precision of 10 and a scale of 2.
You can adjust the precision and scale to fit your data. DESC specifies that you want to sort the result in descending order.
By using this approach, you will be able to sort both integer and floating-point values in descending order correctly.
The CAST() function will ensure that the values are treated as numeric values for sorting.